# UITableView doesn't call numberOfRowsInSection nor cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I don't know what to think...
I set up my main view to contain a `UITableView`. (I am using a UIPickerView as well on that view.)

I defined it to conform to the protocols:

```
UIPickerViewDelegate,
UIPickerViewDataSource,
UITableViewDataSource,
UITableViewDelegate
```

Announced the two methods in my view's h:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

implemented them in m:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %d",indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}
```

I did set the delegate in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
searchTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
[searchTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(searchBar.frame.origin.x+10, 50, searchBar.frame.size.width-20, 300)];
searchTableView.delegate=self;
```

And yet, not numberOfRowsInSection nor cellForRowAtIndexPath are ever called!

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: have you set the data source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the datasource:

```
[searchTableView setDataSource:self];
```